# Apply CSS to a class or ID when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to apply CSS to a specific class when clicking on a `<a href="" class="" id="">`

I'm using a modal which it should cover the whole screen when clicked but for some reason when clicked, everything is covered except the Header (logo/menu).

What I wanted to do is apply `z-index` when I click on the modal and apply a revert `z-index` when I close the modal when clicking the x button.

Is something that it can be done?

Yes, I've tried to find something that I can use but no luck at all.

---

Update:

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyNiq.png)

If you see the photo, you'll see that the x button is behind the MENU.

```
<a class="vPlay vPlay-btn clickformodal" href="#modal-our-work-1" data-toggle="modal" data-video="241737557"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/play1.png" /></a>
```

When this is clicked, the modal opens.

Now the idea is to apply a z-index to the header so it doesn't go above the modal as in the photo, but only when this button is clicked ( or better said for that id="clickformodal" )

Then, when a close button is clicked, to apply another z-index style to the header so it appears when modal is closed.

Does it make sense?

another update:

tried this code from a user suggestion but not working

```
let open = document.selectElementByClassName("clickformodal");
let header = document.selectElementByClassName("mk-header");
let close = document.selectElementByClassName("close");


open.addEventListener('click', function () {
   header.classList.add("headerbefore");
});

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
   header.classList.remove("headerafter");
});
```

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Post you code to show what you've tried so far, and others would be able to help. Add details whether you are using any JS framework etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let open = document.getElementByClassName("class-name-of-open-button")[0];
let header = document.getElementByClassName("class-name-of-header")[0];
let close = document.getElementByClassName("class-name-of-x-button")[0];


open.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.add("newStyle");
})

close.addEventListener('click', function () {
  header.classList.remove("newStyle");
})

//in css file

newStyle {
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

If using ids instead of classes use selectElementById instead of selectElementByClassName. You can also use querySelectorAll which should cover either.

If that doesn't work, try posting your css classes/ids that are applied to the header. There could be something funky there causing it.

Comment: I updated your code in my original post, it's not working, unfortunately, please take a look.

Comment: I've updated your code as select it wouldn't work so get was suggested and added [0];. Anyway, you were very helpful so I'm marking your answer as a correct one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Give your modal an id in the html, and target it with JS.

```
<button id="open-modal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="modal">
  /* Other elements */
</div>
```

Javascript would look something like this:

```
const openModal = document.getElementById('open-modal');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
openModal.addEventListener('click', function () {
  modal.style.zIndex = '1000';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try the code below, added some comments to help you figure out what to do.

```
<div class="modal" id="my-modal">
    hello
</div>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="my-modal">Toggle</button>

<style>
    .addIndex { z-index: 9999999; }
    .modal{position: absolute; top: -100%; left: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 9999; width: 100%; height: 100%; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
    .modal.show{top: 0;}
</style>

<script>
    var modal = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-toggle=modal]");

    [].forEach.call(modal, function(md){
        if (md.hasAttribute('data-target'))
        {
            var target = md.getAttribute("data-target");
            var loadtarget = document.getElementById(target);

            //open modal
            md.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                // add css addIndex class name to modal
                // it then become class="modal show addIndex"
                loadtarget.className += 'show addIndex';
                var closebtn = document.createElement("span");
                closebtn.className = "closebtn";
                closebtn.innerHTML = '&times;';
                loadtarget.appendChild(closebtn);

                // close modal
                closebtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    // revert to original css class name
                    // it become class="modal"
                    loadtarget.className = "modal";
                    loadtarget.removeChild(closebtn);
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps; Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to use Vue or something like that but here's what I came up with just using vanilla JS. Hope it helps!

```js
(function() {

  // makeshift router
  function changeView(num) {
    var views = document.querySelectorAll('div.view');
    for (var x = 0; x < views.length; x++) {
      views[x].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('view-' + num).style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  // event listeners for links
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('div.navbar-link');
  for (var x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
    links[x].onclick = function() {
      changeView(parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-view')));
    }
  }

  // load init view
  changeView(1);

})();
```

```css
div.view {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
}

div#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div#navbar div {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px 15px;
}

div#navbar div:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div#view-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

div#view-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

div#view-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-link" data-view="1">Homepage</div>
  <div class="navbar-link" data-view="2">Projects</div>
  <div class="navbar-link" data-view="3">Contact</div>
</div>
<div id="view-1" class="view">Homepage</div>
<div id="view-2" class="view">Projects</div>
<div id="view-3" class="view">Contact</div>
```